# Is std::is_trivially_copyable wrong?

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits, std

Considering cppreference and the current c++ working draft, a class is trivially copyable if:

1. Every copy constructor is trivial or deleted
2. Every move constructor is trivial or deleted
3. Every copy assignment operator is trivial or deleted
4. Every move assignment operator is trivial or deleted
5. **at least one copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator is non-deleted**
6. Trivial non-deleted destructor

   - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable
   - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable
   - https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4750.pdf (page 215)

So I came up with this code sample:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct non_trivially_copyable {
  non_trivially_copyable(non_trivially_copyable const&) = delete;
  non_trivially_copyable& operator=(non_trivially_copyable const&) = delete;
  non_trivially_copyable(non_trivially_copyable &&) = delete;
  non_trivially_copyable& operator=(non_trivially_copyable &&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    return std::is_trivially_copyable<non_trivially_copyable>::value;
}
```

My class does not satisfy requirement number 5. Still it gives me the result that my class `non_trivially_copyable` is trivially copyable. I tested it on some online compilers:

- https://godbolt.org/g/9s4fr9
- https://wandbox.org/permlink/sEJYdi5aIDMzsjGY
- https://onlinegdb.com/SyFyTBrx7
- http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93b6ea4d202092a6

I doubt that all implementations are wrong; so why do I get this result?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was changed in C++17; before that, `non_trivially_copyable` would have been trivially copyable. Your class is indeed not trivially copyable in C++17, by the part of the standard you refer to yourself.

However, it appears libstdc++ and libc++ were not updated to reflect that yet. So to answer your question directly: those two implementations are indeed wrong.
Note that your godbolt link shows that MSVC does get it right.

As this was considered a defect (see [CWG 1734](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1734)), this is supposed to change for implementations of older revisions of C++, too.

---

As far as I know, one core motivation for the change in the standard was to make `memcpy`-ing around atomics and mutexes illegal.

Comment: okay, so i got it conceptually right :P i guess other implementations will follow msvc with the "right" thing sometime?

Comment: @phön Yes, sooner or later, the other implementations should become conforming, too. C++17 is still quite new; it usually can take a bit until all changes to the standard are fully implemented.